# Who was R' Yosef Angeloni?

Tags: rabbis, historical-figures

The *sefer* [חצי מנשה](http://hebrewbooks.org/5919) (R' Menashe Grossberg, 1860-1927, brief bio excerpted from Encyclopedia Judaica [here](http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/author/MAIMONIDES,-MOSES-AND-MENASSEH-GROSSBERG)) [refers](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=5919&st=&pgnum=21) to a R' Yosef Angeloni (אנגילוני) who authored a *sefer* entitled קופת הרוכלים that is supposedly in manuscript at Oxford.

R' M.M. Kasher (in *Torah Sheleima*) cites R' Angeloni via R' Grossberg in multiple instances, such as in the link provided in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33501).

Who was R' Yosef Angeloni?

(Information on when and where he lived and on his *sefer* would be appreciated, as would any other biographical details).

Comment: @wfb how do you know?

Comment: @msh210 That's what the Encyclopedia Judaica goes with, too, but why?

Comment: @msh210 Truth is, now that you bring it up I'm not sure any more. I just assumed that would be a better book title.

Comment: @wfb I just changed it to Hebrew. Incidentally, are you aware of any sources indicating a relationship between Menashe (or at least Yosef) and (specifically) arrows?

Comment: @Fred, [_B'reshis_ 48:22](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%97_%D7%9B%D7%91) (_Yosef_, not _M'nashe_).

Comment: @msh210 That occurred to me too, but it's Ya'akov for Yosef, so I think it's just too far removed for anyone to name a sefer "Menashe's Arrows" on that account.

Comment: @Fred I agree completely.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this source](http://hsf.bgu.ac.il/cjt/files/electures/glRAngelit.htm),

> Rabbi Joseph Angelit of Spain was a Cabbalist who lived in Saragosa in
>   the first half of the 14th century. (Scholars had originally believed
>   his name was Angelino, and that he was Italian, but this was a scribal
>   error). He authored several books including Sefer Livnat Sapir, Sefer
>   Kupat Rokhlin, a commentary on Sha'arei Orah, Kaf Dalet Yesodot, and
>   he also refers to a commentary on Aggadot and a Sefer Mitzvoth that he
>   wrote, but these are not been found. The date he gives for writing his
>   Livnat Sapir is 1327, and according to Spanish archival material he
>   was present during an arbitration proceedings that took place in
>   Sarragosa in 1335.  Some of his writing is in the style of the Zohar
>   and Yehudah Libes has suggested not only that he himself thought of
>   his writing as contiguous with Zohar Literature, but that bits of his
>   writings have in fact been included in the Zohar.  See: Iris Felix,
>   The Kabbalistic Thought of Rabbi Joseph Angelit, M.A. thesis,
>   1991.[Hebrew]

His sefer Livnat ha-Sapir is available [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/32864), and [here](https://www.academia.edu/2049659/11._R._Joseph_Angelet_and_his_Zoharic_Writings_Hebrew_-_) is an article about his Zoharic writings.